# Newbie trying to display two images side by side using Scala.Swing

Tags: swing, scala

I'm trying to make an application where you can flip through pages.

I was hoping this code would display two images (001.jpg, 002.jpg) side by side, but instead I don't get anything.

```
import java.awt.Dimension
import javax.swing.ImageIcon

import scala.swing.event.UIElementResized
import scala.swing.{BorderPanel, BoxPanel, Label, MainFrame, Orientation, SimpleSwingApplication}

object CViewerMainWindow extends SimpleSwingApplication {
    var i = 0

    def drawPages(left: Label, right: Label, size: Dimension): Unit = {
        //resize to match window
    }

    def top = new MainFrame {
        title = "Work in Progress"
        preferredSize = new Dimension(320, 240)
        var leftPage = new Label {new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/001.jpg")}
        var rightPage = new Label {new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/002.jpg")}
        // maximize
        visible = true
//      contents = new BorderPanel {
//          layout(leftPage) = BorderPanel.Position.West
//          layout(rightPage) = BorderPanel.Position.East
//      }
        contents = new BorderPanel {
            layout(new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
                contents += leftPage
            }) = BorderPanel.Position.West
            layout(new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
                contents += rightPage
            }) = BorderPanel.Position.East
        }

        // contents = new Label("Here is the contents!")
        listenTo(this)
        reactions += {
            case UIElementResized(source) =>
                println(source.size)
                drawPages(leftPage, rightPage, size)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by replacing

```
var leftPage = new Label {
  new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/001.jpg")
}
var rightPage = new Label {
  new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/002.jpg")
}
```

with this code

```
var leftPage = new Label {
  icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/001.jpg")
}
var rightPage = new Label {
  icon = new ImageIcon("/Users/Matt/learning-scala/learning-GUI/002.jpg")
}
```

Instead of just giving the Label the ImageIcon, you apparently have to set its icon to the ImageIcon you want.